# How to use setInterval properly in javascript to render data synchronously?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, setinterval

I want to show data(events) in DOM that occur in certain time, after get them via http request, for example:

```
[{
 milliseconds: 1,
 event: "Buton change red",
},
{
 milliseconds: 2,
 event: "A comment written",
}]
```

And then reproduce in DOM like a "replay"

Is there any way to use setInterval or something efficiently to achieve this and ensure performance?

Comment: look at [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: well a difference of a millisecond is not going to be noticeable.

Comment: Yes, I know, it  is just as an example